# TextWatcher slow when using setText

Tags: android

I'm using `TextWatcher` to modify the `EditText` to always look like `#tag1 #tag2...`

Here is my code:

```
    editHashtags.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private boolean lock = false;
        private String toGo;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(before == 1) return;

            toGo = s.toString();

            if(toGo.charAt(0) != '#') {
                toGo = '#' + toGo;
            }

            if(toGo.charAt(start) == ' ' && toGo.charAt(start - 1) == '#' && start > 0
            || toGo.charAt(start) == ' ' && toGo.charAt(start - 1) == ' ' && start > 0) {
                toGo = toGo.substring(0, toGo.length() - 1);
            } else if(toGo.charAt(start) == ' ') {
                toGo += '#';
            } else if(toGo.charAt(start) != '#' && toGo.charAt(start - 1) == ' ') {
                toGo = toGo.substring(0, toGo.length() - 1) + '#' + toGo.charAt(start);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(lock) return;

            toGo = toGo.replaceAll("#+", "#");

            lock = true;
            editHashtags.setText(toGo);
            editHashtags.setSelection(toGo.length());
            lock = false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is when I use `lock` to change the text. It appears that `setText` is really slow, so if I type fast, some characters are ignored.

What is the best approach to solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to modify a `EditText` using `TextWatcher` is modifying the mutable object `Editable` received on the `afterTextChanged` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at implementing a custom [TransformationMethod](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod.html) instead, which might give you better performance. An implementation similar to the framework's [ReplacementTransformationMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/method/ReplacementTransformationMethod.java), for instance.